# Devise sign-up successful, login unsuccessful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

As the title says, I correctly sign-up using the username and password field in devise. However, when I try to login the `'Invalid Email, Login or password'` is displayed. The username is stored as seen on the rails console, however, the password isn't encrypted or shown here:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 9, email: "", created_at: "2016-12-01 16:32:20", updated_at: "2016-12-01 16:32:20", username: "benjamin">]>
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: [:username, :password]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: [:username, :password]
  end


end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :stories
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}
  validates_format_of :username, with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*$/, :multiline => true
  attr_accessor :login
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => {email: true, login: false}

 def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
        where(conditions.to_h).first
      end
    end

def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end

end
```

My DB files are relevant:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using confirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    

    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

/

```
class RemoveEmailUniquenessFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :users, :email, :string, unique: false
  end
end
```

/

```
class RemoveIndexFromUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    
def change
remove_index :users, :email
end

end
```

Edit:

```
I have changed devise params to:

    def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_in, keys: [:username, :password]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: [:username, :password, :password_confirmation]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: [:username, :password, :password_confirmation]
  end
```

Still having

> 'invalid, email, login or password'

Answer (score 0):

In here:

`def configure_permitted_parameters
  added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: [:username, :password]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: [:username, :password]
end`

You aren't using the `added_attrs` variable. I'm guessing you need to also permit those fields.

Comment: What should I change? I have tried to configure the parameters and displayed them above, in my edited post. Unfortunately, still not working.

Comment: If you go into the console and run `User.create username: 'whatever', password: 'password'` what do you get? Does that save the password? Can you log in to the site with that user after that?

Comment: I think I was wrong about needing password_confirmation, that was an older version of Devise where that was required.